# Conditional attribute with Riot.js

Tags: riot.js

How can I conditionally add an attribute with Riot.js?

Suppose I have the following:

```
<progress max="10" value="{progressValue}"></progress>
```

This sets the `value` attribute to whatever `progressValue` is.  However, there may be cases where I don't want to add this attribute at all.  Specifically in this example, if I want the progress element to have an indeterminate state, I need to remove the `value` attribute entirely.

I know that for some attributes ([such as `disabled`](https://github.com/riot/riot/issues/1453)), there is special handling.  Is it configurable somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers give non ideal solutions.

Generally all attributes can be removed by passing a falsy expression in the same way as boolean atributes, e.g. `<div class={ null }></div>` will be rendered as `<div></div>`.

But values attributes are special ones: on form elements it is not recomended to set them using `setAttribute` ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470788)), so they are handled using an ad hoc binding expression different from the one of generic attributes.
This binding expression seems to have a different behaviour with falsy values so the previous example does not work. It is probably a bug, I'll update the answer when this behaviour will be cleared.

**Update**:
The problem has been fixed in Riot.js 4.3.7

Answer (score 0):

> I know that for some attributes (such as disabled), there is special handling. Is it configurable somehow?

no, attributes like `disabled` or `checked` are evaluated by browsers as true when just the attribute is present, they do not require a value, that's why there is special handling for them.

to set it dynamically you could probably NOT use an expression but the `this.$()` DOM  helper to set the attribute, e.g. somewhere suitable do:

```
if ( <var-to-add-attr> ) {
    this.$('progress').setAttribute('value', progress);
}

if ( <var-to-remove-attr> ) {
    this.$('progress').removeAttribute('value')
}
```

although untested something in that direction could work.

Answer (score 0):

On riot.js I prefer to use if or show attributes:

Create your tag component using show or if:

```
<progress>
    <div show={ opts.loading }>
        your HTML here
    </div>
</progress>
```

Using if:

```
<progress>
    <div if={ opts.loading }>
        your HTML here
    </div>
</progress>
```

You can call your component like this:

```
<progress loading={ this.loading }></progress>

<script>
    this.loading = true // add your code logic here
    this.update()
</script>
```

Don't worry about remove the loading attribute, when you do this.update() the riot.js will do that for you if the value is false.

**EDIT**

If you are using Riot.js >= 4.0 use props instead opts